# Replacing all instances of a character in a string only using loops

Tags: java, string, loops

So as the title suggests I have a homework problem that I'm having trouble solving. Using only the basic string methods (length, charAt, substring, equals, equalsIgnoreCase) and loops, I have to replace all instances of a character in a user inputted string and print the new string with the new character the user wants in place of the old.  I'm not sure how to locate and store all the instances of the character of a string without using indexOf. This is some basic code I've written and any guidance would be appreciated. I do not know how to replace all instances of a character using only these basic string methods.

```
        String letter;

        System.out.println("Enter the character you want to replace");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();

        int characterAt = 0;
        for (characterAt = 0; characterAt < savedInput.length(); characterAt++)
        {
            letter = "" + savedInput.charAt(characterAt);
                if(input.equals(letter))
            {
                System.out.println("Enter the new character");
                input = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("The new string is: " );

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do it. You can convert your `String` to an array of `characters` - [String#toCharArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--). And then you need to iterate over the array and replace char with new value.

```
char[] chars = "lorem ipsum sit amet".toCharArray();
char newValue = 'X';
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
      if (chars[i] == 'm') {
          chars[i] = newValue;
      }
}
System.out.println(new String (chars)); // loreX ipsuX sit aXet
```

You might want to use `StringBuilder` for similar solution:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("lorem ipsum sit amet");
char newValue = 'X';
for (int i = 0; i < builder.length(); i++) {
    if (builder.charAt(i) == 'm') {
        builder.setCharAt(i, newValue);
    }
}
System.out.println(builder); // loreX ipsuX sit aXet
```

You can even use `stream` API for that as well:

```
String newString = "lorem ipsum sit amet".chars().map(el -> {
    if ((char) el == 'm') {
        return 'X';
    } else {
        return el;
    }
}).collect(StringBuilder::new,
        StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
        .toString();
System.out.println(newString); // loreX ipsuX sit aXet
```